# Change image without changing source

Tags: html, image

Is it even possible to??

I have the following code on my webpage

`<img src="abc.png" height=500 onmouseover="this.src='def.png'" onmouseout="this.src='abc.png'">`

(abc.png has a black arrow and def.png has the same image in white color)

which is working fine offline. But if I put it online, it takes time to load the second image and meanwhile that area is blank which looks very bad.

So can I change the color of arrow in image without changing source?? Or can I do something to quicken this process?? Can anyone help me?? Your help is much appreciated

Comment: You cant use onmouseover directly please use jquery / javascript to change image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load another img tag with "display: none" and with the second image.

Than replace the source. The image is already cached.

You can even remove the img tag later.

Answer (score 1):

Display your image, and wrap it in a DIV which is the same dimensions as the image.  On the DIV add a background-image.  When a visitors loads your webpage both the background-image and the image will be loaded but they won't see the background-image because it's covered by the image.  When you want to display the other image, hide the image and they will see the background-image which was there all along.  If the image has an alpha channel, you'll need to nest the image two levels, placing the background-image on the outer most div, and placing a background color on the inner div.

```
<div width="200" height="200" style="background:url('http://www.placehold.it/200/200/cccccc') no-repeat center;">
    <div width="200" height="200" bgcolor="#ffffff"><!-- hide this div to display the background image -->
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200/200/aaaaaa' alt="Transparent png image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If the images are just arrows or any shape that could easily be a vector, what I prefer to do is create glyphs out of all my commonly used icons and append them as additional characters in a web-font that I'm already including on the site.  It's very easy to do this with [FontLab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/) which is available for OSX or Windows.  FontLab isn't free, but if you want a free alternative there's also [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/), also available for OSX or Windows, which I've used as well and it's just as good as FontLab but can be a bit of a process to get it set up.

The benefit of making them glyphs is they become very flexible to manipulate, as well as provide the greatest level of optimization.  Adding a few glyphs to a font file your already including means that they are not more than a couple of bytes in size at most, and as font characters, you can adjust the size, color, and position of them as easily as you would any textual content.

Of course this isn't a feasible solution if you don't have a web-font already in place because adding a web-font simply for this affect would negate the benefit gained in optimization, and wouldn't be worth the level of compatibility you lose.  Web-fonts are to some degree less cross-compatible than using images.  A way to minimize this is by ensuring that you have a proper font stack that includes variants that each browser supports.

---

If you don't want to do it yourself, I believe there are free services online that enable you to convert icons to glyphs as well.  Though I can't speak on the level of quality because I've always done it on my own.  The first one that comes up in a search is [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/#docs)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code...

```
$("img.imgchange").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).attr("src","def.png");
});


$("img.imgchange").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).attr("src","def.png");
});
```

To Remove Blank while loading image use background image for image tag like below

```
<img src="abc.png" style="background-image:url('loading.gif');" class="imgchange" height=500 onmouseover="this.src='def.png'" onmouseout="this.src='abc.png'">
```

For mouse enter use function `mouseenter()`